# Remove element from array and return only remaining elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove one element from an array and return only the remaining elements.

I tried with `splice` and `filter` but can't get it to work.

With `splice` it only returns the removed element, I need the opposite.

```
var parse_obj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('imagens').value);
function rImagem(data){
    data = data - 1;
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn_remover")[data].style.display = 'none';
    parse_obj2 = parse_obj.splice(parse_obj.findIndex(e => e.data,1));
    new_string = JSON.stringify(parse_obj2);
    document.getElementById('imagens').value = new_string;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `parse_obj`? `.splice()` changes the array in-place, so once you run `parse_obj.splice` it would be the array with the item removed.

Comment: splice returns the removed elements array. can you add random data ? filter should work

Comment: `splice()` method returns the deleted element from the array. You are trying to assign this deleted element in the array `parse_obj2`. What you should do is not assign anything to the variable `parse_obj2` and use the `parse_obj` array as it is.

`parse_obj.splice(parse_obj.findIndex(e => e.data,1));`

`new_string = JSON.stringify(parse_obj2);`

Answer (score 12):

In your scenario you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Syntax) to filter the indexes you don't want in the resulting array. The first param of the callback you pass in the filter is the current element `ele` and the second is the index of the current element `idx`:

```
parse_obj2 = parse_obj.filter((ele, idx) => idx !== parse_obj.findIndex(e => e.data,1));
```

Here, lets say I want to remove the element at the third index so I would compare the current index in the filter function callback with the index of the element I want to remove. It will result in a new array with all the elements of the original array only without the element whose index I wanted to remove.

```js
var indexToRemove = 2; 
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = arr.filter((data, idx) => idx !== indexToRemove );
console.log(result);
```

The same result cam be obtained through `splice` also.

```
parse_obj.splice(parse_obj.findIndex(e => e.data,1), 1); //parse_obj is one element less.
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var indexToRemove = 2; 
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.splice(indexToRemove, 1); //removes only the third element and modifies the original array in place.
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) is actually what you are looking for. The problem is, splice doesn't **return** the new array, it removes the element(s) from the array and returns the deleted elements. However, in the original array you will have the same elements except the removed ones.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(`Array elements before splice: ${array}`);
console.log(`Deleted elements: ${array.splice(1, 2)}`);
console.log(`Array elements after splice: ${array}`);
```

If you don't wish to modify the original array, though, you can always use filter:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let toDelete = [2, 4];

console.log(`Original array elements: ${array}`);
console.log(`Elements to delete: ${toDelete}`);

let newArray = array.filter(n => !toDelete.includes(n));
console.log(`Array elements after splice: ${newArray}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    function remove(arr,index){
    return arr.slice(0,index).concat(arr.slice(index+1,9))
    }
    
   // remove(<your array over here>,<the index of the element that you want to remove>) 
   // ex -   
    remove(myarray,0);
```

**Hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

Hey I ran across a simple solution to this without using splice() using destructuring.

```
const myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function removeFirst(array){
const [a, ...arr] = array; //a is never returned
return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
    var filtered = array.filter(function(value, index, arr){ 
        return value > 5;
    });
    //filtered => [6, 7, 8, 9]
    //array => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to know how to use splice. Hope this below answers your question.

```
const months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(1, 0, 'Feb');
// Inserts at index 1
console.log(months);
// Expected output: Array ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "June"]

months.splice(4, 1,"May");
// Replaces 1 element at index 4
console.log(months);
// Expected output: Array ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May"]


months.splice(4, 1);
// Replaces 1 element at index 4
console.log(months);
// Expected output: Array ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April" ]
```